# Host rails apps from apache userdirs (mod_userdir)

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a server where we have mod_userdir setup, allowing users to use their public_html space to host webpages under (for example):

http://example.com/~user/

Where "user" is the username, and points to /home/user/public_html/.

Is there a way for me to allow users to host rails apps in their public_html directories?

Comment: I understand the rails app would need to execute code on the server, and the users may not have permissions to do this right now.

Comment: have you try out how to do this now? (2015-01-19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't currently seem to be possible. See http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_mod_userdir